Find source of bandwidth cap
Good day!
There is a group of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS workstations at work that me and my coworker use to run different kinds of jobs. Both me and another coworker are sudoers on the machines, and we are controlling what gets installed on them. So it came at a surprise to me that, despite not having any software in place to control internet access (except ufw set up to block non-ssh incoming connections), my and only my user account has begun having its internet access seemingly capped at 0.05mbps on machines with server hardware and 5mbps on normal workstations. The machines are supposed to have gigabit internet, and no other users or programs are using the network either.
My other coworkers do not experience this, but anytime I try to use wget, apt, or anything that downloads files, it becomes very apparent and annoying. I've been working mostly from home lately, so I might have only been experiencing this while working over SSH, if that is relevant, although my coworkers could not replicate the issue over ssh either.
Since we do not even have anything in place to impose these kinds of limits, I am at a loss and do not know where to even begin to investigate. Some googling showed me the tc command, but querying the tc command I don't see any specific filters, classes or anything out of the ordinary generally.
Would you have any idea of what could be causing this?

Linux generally does not keep track of which users are using network resources. Check perhaps if the iptables rules use the -m or --match option. But if you find anything, this would be simply sabotage.

I have checked the iptables, I don't see anything like this. In fact the rules looked like extremely straightforward defaults and made me realize ufw wasn't even active either :/

Another possible direction is if the router has per-user QoS or traffic shaping.
